# SNAT& iptables in Centos

Tags: centos, iptables, failover, aliases

i have a remote server where I have added a new **FAILOVER IP** in a new interface, **ETH0:0**. Everything works perfectly; IP is setup. I want the traffic that is coming from **ETH0:0** to use the **ETH0:0** as the IP source. For example, when I send emails from my SERVER it uses The **ETH0** IP which is not what I want.

So, the traffic coming from **ETH0** use its IP in Source IP of The Packet, and the traffic coming from **ETH0:0** uses its IP and so on. Here is what I have tried:

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -o eth0:0 -j SNAT --to-source 51.XXX.XXX.XXX ;

Where the interface ETH0:0 Has the IP **51.XXX.XXX.XXX**

Answer (score 0):

Almost every server has option to bind it to selected IP/interface. You have to set it to the IP on interface eth0:0.

For postfix check http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html option inet_interfaces.

In /etc/postfix/main.cf add/change line:

```
inet_interfaces = 51.XXX.XXX.XXX, 127.0.0.1
```

This will ensure proper IP for outgoing packets but server will be accessible only on IP 51.XXX.XXX.XXX and 127.0.0.1.

Similar configuration change can be done in your server software.
Probable options names: bind, listen.